# Why can't I use database set defaults?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Why can't I use database set defaults with Entity Framework? When I designed my database, I added appropriate default values (i.e. "Default Value or Binding" field). Now it seems that I have to specify those default in my code anyway unless I use `StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed` but then I am not allowed to change the value later. If I don't specify a default value in code, I get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is some logic here.

In your entity you have public int ExampleInt { get; set; }. Let say you set The default value of Example column to 100.

Imagine the situation where the entity object is created. It's a C# object with default values being filled in by the runtime.  ExampleInt is initialized with value 0. At this time, entity object knows nothing about db. Then you decide to save the entity. EF will have to create a row and then insert the values you specified. But wait? Should this be 0 or 100? EF would have to track if you made a change to the field, but if you create entity object, EF is not aware of it until you attach it/save it.

Just an idea: What if you run in constructor a query to check the default value? This will work as the moment you create the object it will be filled with the default value. If the object is created by EF, that value will be overwritten by what you have in db. Actually, I got a better idea.

Why don't you use factory to create new entity objects? The factory can query the db for default value? It's still not really nice, but much better that running a query in constructre. So:

```
public class ExampleFactory
{
   public static GetExample ()
   {
       // obviously you want to run it only once. This is example only.
       int defaultValue = dbContext.Database.SQLQuery("SqlToGetTheDefaultValue");
       return new Example { ExampleInt = defaultValue };
   }
}
```

So there you go. Now you know why EF can't do this. And I also gave you (bad) idea, of how can you tackle this.

Comment: But it would be nice if the EF metadata could contain the default value, and be updated whenever the database was updated. I just do not like having constant values in more than one place. *sigh*

Comment: I agree, it could be nice. http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions

Comment: Did you see that: "Properties with StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed can be set in the application but the value is not used. The only exceptions are properties with ConcurrencyMode.Fixed. These properties are used but only if you set them when the entity is not tracked by a context. I will further discuss this in another blog post because it is the big issue in optimistic concurrency handling in Entity Framework." http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/